# React form still refreshes even after addying event.prefeventDefault

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone explain to me why my react form is still refreshing after submitting? I'm making a simple todo list to get familiar with react and I can't seem to figure out this bug. What I'm trying to do is add a task to a list, the display that list. Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/Jake-Mullen/pen/YZZmjX) to see my code, sorry for the poor formatting.

```
class TaskList extends React.Component {
 render() {
 var taskEntries = this.props.entries;

 function createTasks(task) {
  return <li key={task.key}>{task.text}</li>
 }

 var listTasks = taskEntries.map(createTasks);

 return (
   <ul>
     {listTasks}
   </ul>
   );
  }
}

class Task extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
   tasks: [],
 };
 this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
}

addTask(evt) {
 evt.preventDefault;
 var taskArray = this.state.tasks;

taskArray.push(
   {
    text: this.textInput.value,
    key: Date.now()
   }
);

this.setState({
  tasks: taskArray
});
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.addTask}>
      <label htmlFor="title">Title of Task</label>
      <input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
      <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <TaskList entries={this.state.tasks} />
  </div>
);
 }
}

var destination = document.querySelector(".container");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Task />,
  destination
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change

```
evt.preventDefault
```

to

```
evt.preventDefault()
```

Comment: he had the ; at the end though ;-)

Comment: Oh jeeze, that's embarrassing. Thanks you! :)